# For $n > 2$ there are no positive integers $x,y,z$ satisfying $x^n+y^n=z^n$ (A question from my teacher)

Tags: number-theory

I'm a junior in high school right now and for my Advanced Math class we're doing a unit on intro to proofs. This is one of our extra credit questions this week and I'm not quite sure where to start. We've discussed proof by contradiction and induction but I can seem to figure out how to apply either to this problem.

> Prove that there are no positive integers $x$, $y$, and $z$ that satisfy
>   $$
> x^n + y^n = z^n
> $$
>   if $n > 2$.

My teacher said that it's pretty easy once you see the "trick". He said his solution is only like three lines.

Comment: He's trolling you. [No elementary proof of this theorem is known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_last_theorem).

Comment: You beat me by 29 seconds!

Answer (score 3):

This is **[Fermat's Last Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem)**, a result which took Andrew Wiles hundreds of pages to prove. Your teacher was joking, trolling, or both. Or: you misheard her question.

Comment: How would I go about proving it though? I really need to get this extra credit point! I'm willing to spend a few hours reading Wikipedia pages if that's what it takes.

Comment: You wouldn't! It's not something you can prove. It wasn't until the 1990s until this result was proven and it contains very very advanced topics that escaped the minds of several mathematicians. These topics included elliptical geometry and analytic number theory. The proof is several pages long and you should not waste your time attempting it. Tell your teacher this.

Comment: @AhaanRungta "Several pages" is a little of an understatement! The main paper (109 pages) is here: http://math.stanford.edu/~lekheng/flt/wiles.pdf, and depends on results from other papers (co-)authored by Wiles.

Comment: @MattPressland Yeah, I knew it was more than 100 pages, but I just didn't want to exaggerate by saying "hundreds of pages!"

Comment: @AhaanRungta Haha, it is annoyingly difficult to describe something about 100 pages long via hyperbole! "Hundreds of pages" is innaccurate, and "tens of pages" just doesn't have the right impact. If you really want the extra credit point, then "see *Modular Elliptic Curves and Fermat's Last Theorem*, by Andrew Wiles" should be sufficient. (Although if your teacher doesn't have the right sense of humour to appreciate that, then I didn't tell you to say it!)

Comment: Not merely 109 pages but hundreds of years as well.

Comment: I assure you with absolute certainty, your teacher himself does not know how to prove this. For hundreds of years this was one of the most famous unsolved problems.  It was controversial when it was proven in the 90's and it took several years for people to verify it was indeed a correct proof.  Your teacher *is* joking.  You may (or may not) get extra credit points for recognizing that it is Fermat's Last Theorem and spending a few hours on a wikipedia learning about the history, but there is no way, you (or me, or your teacher) will be able to follow the proof.